# iptables: 0.0.38.69 ACCEPT?

Tags: debian, iptables, hacking

Just looking at the firewall rules on a Debian Lenny box with "iptables -L". One entry is scaring me:

ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.38.69            anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             0.0.38.69

This is not coming from any of my scripts - what could it be?

Thanks!

Comment: From which chain / table did you get these rules?

Answer (score 4):

`0.0.0.0/8` is not a usefully routeable netblock. (See [this bogons reference](http://www.team-cymru.org/Services/Bogons/)), so I'd say it's more likely a broken iptables invocation, rather than anything nasty.

Converting that IP to a single, decimal number ([calc here](http://www.allredroster.com/iptodec.htm)), it becomes `9797`, which looks more like a port number. Stretching my guess, you may have a broken `$VARIABLE` reference in your iptables script that's expanding to an empty string, leaving a port number in the wrong place.  That's where I'd start looking, anyway.

Comment: While I agree with your post, I also want to note that it's not uncommon for malicious users to "hijack" unused/unassigned IP networks to use for their purposes...

Comment: Good catch as well--would never have guessed that it may be a port substituted for an IP!

Comment: SmallClanger you rock! It was a bad port 9797 rule. Thanks.